# Delivering docker image to multiple servers without docker machine

Tags: ssh, docker

I have a couple machines running in an isolated environment. They can be accessed via a bastion machine which has a public IP address. I'm currently trying to automate the distribution of docker images created in local machine to machines in the isolated environment.

Currently I have the following command:

```
docker save test/myapp  |  gzip  | pv | ssh ubuntu@bastion "cat > remote"
```

This command copies a file to the bastion machine. The problem is that I don't want anything to be saved in the bastion machine drive.

I want to write a script in the bastion machine that delivers the image to all machines in an isolated environment that don't have public IP address.

I think that I should have some kind of a script in bastion machine that would take input from a pipe.

The script should make an ssh command to each machine and run docker in a load image command. This would be easy to do with a docker machine but I can't use it because it requires Internet connection. Any ideas?

In short: I want to deliver a docker image from local machine to multiple servers via the bastion server.

I am pretty new in this kind of scripting so I'm sorry if my question is trivial but thus far I haven't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use multiple ssh pipes like this:

```
docker save testi/myapp  | gzip  | pv | ssh ubuntu@bastion "cat | pv | ssh ubuntu@host \"docker load\" "
```

This command loads the file to host machine through bastion and file isn't saved in bastion machine.